# jquery pass data from dialog with custom event

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a dialog box that's called inside a parent window. 
That dialog box contains another view (let's call it childView) inside that has, let's say some buttons.
What I'm trying to do is, when a button is clicked, I fire a function that gets 'catched' on the parent window.

Ex:
On parent view:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 530,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("ChildView");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").dialog().dialog('close');
            }
        }).on("ChildButtonClick", function (arg) { alert( "Hello " + arg); })
```

ChildView

```
 ...
 <input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="ClickButton('Bob');" />
 <input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="ClickButton('Alice');" />
  ...


function ClickButton(arg) {

        ...trigger("ChildButtonClick", arg);
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Tks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to do this.

Parent View:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 350,
    width: 530,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load("ChildView.html");
    }
}).on("ChildButtonClick", function (event, data) {
    alert( "Hello " +  data.name);
    })
```

ChildView (ChildView.html):

```
// HTML
<input type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="ClickButton('Bob');" value="Btn1" />
<input type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="ClickButton('Alice');"  value="Btn2" />
// JS
function ClickButton(arg) {
        $("#dialog").trigger("ChildButtonClick", [{name:arg}]);
    }
```

This way, you can catch whatever you pass through the Child in the Parent Window.

Answer (score 0):

good way is to use jQuery libraries, hope my fiddle helps you!

```
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
  .dialog {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute; //this and bootm style gives you that's is a dialog box is over other elements
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Bob" />
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Alice"/>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(e) {
    var self = $(e.currentTarget);
    var name = self.attr('value');
    var html = '<div class="dialog"><button>button 1</button><button>button 2</button><br>Hello '+name+'</div>';

    $('.dialog').remove();
    $('.container').append(html);
  });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1jqq3evc/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){

  // Json Objec
  var user = { 'id' : '123', 'name' : 'Josh' };
  
  $(document).on('click', 'button', {'user' : user}, handlerFunc);
  
  function handlerFunc(evt)
  {
    var user = evt.data.user;
    console.log(user.id)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```